How to do stuff when the console is closed by user (C++)?
I have a program run on a console, and I need to save progress when the user closes the console. How to do it?
Example:
void func()
{
    while (true)
        if (UserClosesTheConsole()) // Dunno how to detect
            SaveProgess();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(func);
}

Any solution (doesn't need to be cross-platform) is welcome.

Are you running on MSWindows?

Yes, I'm running on MSWindows and using MSVC as my compiler and Visual Studio as my environment.

I would do something like this, where I put all the business logic inside a class. This class is then also responsible for managing the lifetime of the mainloop (thread). I also use condition variables to let the mainloop cooperatively shut down in a responisve manner.
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

// It is always a good idea to encapsulate the business logic in a class
// this way you can control the lifetime of the business logic
// and the runtime state of it. This is especially important when
// you have background threads running that you need to stop gracefully.
class BusinessLogic
{
public:
    BusinessLogic() = default;

    ~BusinessLogic()
    {
        Stop();
    }

    // There is a chance for a small race condition where starting a thread
    // will return before the background thread is actually scheduled.
    // So wait for the mainloop to have really started (thread scheduled) before continuing.
    void Run()
    {
        m_thread = std::thread{ [this] { Mainloop(); } };
        WaitForState(State::Running); // Wait for mainloop to have really started
    }

    // Stop the business logic
    // this can happen because main asks it to stop or the signal handler asks it to stop
    void Stop()
    {
        // if already stopped do nothing
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mutex };
            if(m_state == State::Stopped)
                return;
        }
        SetState(State::Stopping);
        WaitForState(State::Stopped); // Wait for mainloop to have really stopped
    }

    void SaveProgress()
    {
        std::cout << "Saving progress\n";
    }

private:
    // state of the business logic/mainloop
    enum class State
    {
        Initial,
        Starting,
        Running,
        Stopping,
        Stopped
    };

    // use a condition variable to signal state changes
    void SetState(State state)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mutex };
        m_state = state;
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    // use the condition varibale to wait for state changes
    void WaitForState(State state)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mutex };
        m_cv.wait(lock, [this, state] { return m_state == state; });
    }

    void Mainloop()
    {
        SetState(State::Running);
        while(true)
        {
            std::cout << "." << std::flush; // show mainloop is still running

            // Using a condition variable with a timeout allows for a clean and responsive shutdown
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mutex };
            m_cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1), [this] { return m_state == State::Stopping; });

            // Check if we should stop (cooperative shutdown of the thread)
            if(m_state == State::Stopping)
            {
                SaveProgress();
                break;
            }
        }
        SetState(State::Stopped);
    }

    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    State m_state{ State::Initial };
    std::thread m_thread;
};

// Meyer's singleton
// Allows console handler to access the BusinessLogic instance
BusinessLogic& GetBusinessLogic()
{
    static BusinessLogic businessLogic;
    return businessLogic;
}

BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleHandler(DWORD signal)
{
    if((signal == CTRL_C_EVENT) || (signal == CTRL_BREAK_EVENT) || (signal == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT))
    {
        std::cout << "Control flow abort received\n";
        GetBusinessLogic().Stop();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3)); // Allow user to see the output before finally shutting down
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    auto& businessLogic = GetBusinessLogic();
    auto retval = ::SetConsoleCtrlHandler(SetConsoleHandler, TRUE);

    businessLogic.Run();

    // Allow businessLogic to run for 10 seconds
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    businessLogic.Stop();
    return 0;
}


I think this code is too long and may be shortened. Can you please shorten this code? Perhaps into 20 lines. (PS. When I ran your code it popped up an error, dunno why)

No it is not too long, why do you think so? When working with threads and synchronization there is work to be done to make shutdown behave nicely and correctly (over 30 years experience with that here).

Also what kind of error popped up?

Understood. Thanks for the explanation. (The error: after outputting "..........Saving progress" an error popped up while running ~BusinessLogic(), saying "fatal program exit requested.")

I noticed a difference when running in the debugger (it adds its own extra handler).
